# Laravel getting CSRF token into a mobile app

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, vuejs2, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.6 with Passport and want to [consume my own API with javascript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) from a hybrid mobile app, but can't wrap my head around how to get the CSRF token into the mobile app.

I can't use password grant as I can't securely store the client_secret and I don't want to use the implicit grant as that requires redirecting my users from the first-party app, which makes little sense from a UI standpoint.

What is the normal flow for authenticating my users in my mobile app? Should I disable the CSRF token verification in Laravel for the login route?

Comment: Are you passing the access token in the request header?

Comment: Not sure which token you are referring to... I am passing the 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', header though - according to the docs I should just be able to send a Form with the email and password no?

Comment: What is the grant type that you are using to log in the user and obtain an access token?

Comment: I'm following this (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) <- I'm not too sure which grant type it uses, but it automatically handles access tokens. I'm just hitting the pre-built `/login` endpoint, is this wrong? I can log in fine if I do a GET request to a page with the CSRF token and then pass that token back to the login (via postman) but how does this work in real-world apps?

Comment: You could check out rickshawhobo's solution in the [link](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/369).

Comment: Hey Michal, is your web app using another login service? Is it not using any login service? This sounds like a problem sso could fix but I'm not entirely sure of your environment.

Comment: @linktoahref that link did help but left me a bit more confused - wouldn't creating something to inject the client secret and ID mean that then anyone could authenticate with that endpoint? What tells my server that this is *my* app?